# Redis leaderboard - player data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, redis

I'm using Redis to store player leaderboards. I need to return more than simply their id and score. Should I store necessary user data in Redis hash, or should I get the id's and then simply query the users via Postgresql?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both approaches will work. By keeping the user data in Postgres, you will avoid duplication, so it's probably the way to go for your use case. Otherwise, you can move all the user data to Redis and store it in hashes, which is what I do.